# Generate VCards from Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, automation, contacts, vcf-vcard, vba

I am looking at creating an excel file where I would manually fill in multiple contacts information so that I can export the contacts (one by one) or all of them to individual vcf files within a specified directory.  I imagine that the best way would be through VBA but I am not very knowleadgeable and need a little push.

Please see below screenshot of the excel file with contact fields.

[image]

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

OK, So I have initially started by addressing exporting each row to an individual vcard. I am following the following strategy:

1. Create a temporary new worksheet (tmp)
2. Paste the Headers: 
   BEGIN:VCARD
   VERSION: 3.0
3. Copy paste the 4th row as per my image so that it includes the IDs of for the VCARD and also the row I am trying to export (in this first case row 6).  I paste them transposed to worksheet tmp.

I get stuck at this stage as the way the vcard is used for certain fields is by separating them with ";" and they are in different positions.  I do not know how i can generate these in VBA by looking at the fields of row 4. ie.: N1 and N2 should create me the line: N:Stuart;Carol. And the same happens for the ADR field.

I have the code to generate the VCARD file once this full code is generated.

Any help at this point will be appreciated.

Comment: you may have to emulate an Outlook contact creation and export (see http://www.peculiarities.com/code/vba.html#vcard for Outlook export)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.  Create a class called CContact with getters and setters for these properties.

```
Private mlContactID As Long
Private msLastName As String
Private msFirstName As String
Private msJobTitle As String
Private msCompany As String
Private msDepartment As String
Private msEmail As String
Private msBusinessPhone As String
Private msCellPhone As String
Private msPager As String
Private msFax As String
```

Create a CContacts class to hold all the CContact instances.  In CContacts, create a FillFromRange method to load up all of the contacts.

```
Public Sub FillFromRange(rRng As Range)

    Dim vaValues As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim clsContact As CContact

    vaValues = rRng.Value

    For i = LBound(vaValues, 1) To UBound(vaValues, 1)
        Set clsContact = New CContact
        With clsContact
            .ContactID = vaValues(i, 1)
            .LastName = vaValues(i, 2)
            .FirstName = vaValues(i, 3)
            .JobTitle = vaValues(i, 4)
            .Company = vaValues(i, 5)
            .Department = vaValues(i, 6)
            .Email = vaValues(i, 7)
            .BusinessPhone = vaValues(i, 8)
            .CellPhone = vaValues(i, 9)
            .Pager = vaValues(i, 10)
            .Fax = vaValues(i, 11)
        End With
        Me.Add clsContact
    Next i

End Sub
```

Create procedures to fill the classes, like this

```
Public Sub Auto_Open()

    Initialize

End Sub

Public Sub Initialize()

    Set gclsContacts = New CContacts

    gclsContacts.FillFromRange Sheet1.Range("C6").CurrentRegion

End Sub
```

For this example, I'm using the double click event. When you double click a contact, the vcard is created.  You'll need to modify to use buttons.  Get the TopLeftCell property of the button that was clicked to determine the row.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim lContactID As Long

    lContactID = Me.Cells(Target.Row, 3).Value

    If gclsContacts Is Nothing Then Initialize

    If lContactID <> 0 Then
        gclsContacts.Contact(CStr(lContactID)).CreateVCardFile
    End If

End Sub
```

That gets the ID from column C and calls the CreateVCardFile method to write out the file.

```
Public Sub CreateVCardFile()

    Dim sFile As String, lFile As Long
    Dim aOutput(1 To 12) As String

    lFile = FreeFile
    sFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & Me.VCardFileName

    Open sFile For Output As lFile

    aOutput(1) = gsBEGIN
    aOutput(2) = gsLASTNAME & Me.LastName
    aOutput(3) = gsFIRSTNAME & Me.FirstName
    aOutput(4) = gsTITLE & Me.JobTitle
    aOutput(5) = gsCOMPANY & Me.Company
    aOutput(6) = gsDEPARTMENT & Me.Department
    aOutput(7) = gsEMAIL & Me.Email
    aOutput(8) = gsBUSINESSPHONE & Me.BusinessPhone
    aOutput(9) = gsCELLPHONE & Me.CellPhone
    aOutput(10) = gsPAGER & Me.Pager
    aOutput(11) = gsFAX & Me.Fax
    aOutput(12) = gsEND

    Print #lFile, Join(aOutput, vbNewLine)

    Close lFile

End Sub
```

That's just building a string and writing to a file.  This example isn't to VCard spec, so you'll have to work out those details.  For this method, you'll need some constants and a property that creates the file name.

```
Public Const gsBEGIN As String = "BEGIN:VCARD VERSSION: 3.0"
Public Const gsEND As String = "END"
Public Const gsLASTNAME As String = "N1;"
Public Const gsFIRSTNAME As String = "N2;"
Public Const gsTITLE As String = "TITLE;"
Public Const gsCOMPANY As String = "ORG1;"
Public Const gsDEPARTMENT As String = "ORG2;"
Public Const gsEMAIL As String = "EMAIL,TYPE=WORK;"
Public Const gsBUSINESSPHONE As String = "TEL,TYPE=WORK;"
Public Const gsCELLPHONE As String = "TEL,TYPE=CELL;"
Public Const gsPAGER As String = "TEL,TYPE=PAGER;"
Public Const gsFAX As String = "TEL,TYPE=WORK,TYPE=FAX;"
```

And the file name property

```
Public Property Get VCardFileName() As String

    VCardFileName = Me.LastName & "_" & Me.FirstName & ".vcf"

End Property
```

You can see the omitted details and how it works together by downloading this file.

http://dailydoseofexcel.com/excel/VCardCreator.zip

Comment: This is great Dick, will modify it a little bit so that the VCard fields fall in the correct place. Might revert to you with questions.  Thanks you for your very helpful response.

Comment: Dick, I have made a couple of changes to the code. (if you want I can paste them here on the comments, basically changing the syntax so that the VCF file works.  I am encountering an issue which is when I ommit some information (ie.: email address) and I delete the previously created file and double click on the row for it to get generated again, somehow it uses the previous email address entered, ie doesn't clear the previous data from memory. Where would you change the code so this doesn't happen and if a field is missing it will just display no info.  Thx again

Comment: Change `If gclsContacts Is Nothing Then Initialize` to just `Initialize` in the event procedure.  That will fill the classes from the sheet every time it runs and pick up any changes you made to the spreadsheet.  As long as you don't have a ton of contacts, you probably won't notice the extra processing time.

Comment: Dick, this worked.  I have pretty much finished what I was planning on doing.  How can I send you the final file so that you can update the link you pasted to the file. (this final file also has work address fields).  Additionally, what lines of code would you write so that the file creates automatically contacts for ALL inputted rows instead of having to go one by one?

Comment: Send it to dick@kusleika.com

Answer (score 0):

I have a sample excel sheet and VBA code corresponding to it .
[sample excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilogz.png)

and here is the corresponding VBA code to convert it into vcf type.

```
Private Sub Create_VCF()
'Open a File in Specific Path in Output or Append mode
Dim FileNum As Integer
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim FirstName As String
Dim LastName As String
Dim FullName As String
Dim EmailAddress As String
Dim PhoneHome As String
Dim PhoneWork As String
Dim Organization As String
Dim JobTitle As String


iRow = 3
FileNum = FreeFile
OutFilePath = "C:\output.VCF"
Open OutFilePath For Output As FileNum

'Loop through Excel Sheet each row and write it to VCF File
While VBA.Trim(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, 1)) <> ""



    FirstName = VBA.Trim(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, 1))
    LastName = VBA.Trim(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, 2))
    FullName = VBA.Trim(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, 3))
    EmailAddress = VBA.Trim(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, 4))
    PhoneWork = VBA.Trim(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, 5))
    PhoneHome = VBA.Trim(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, 6))
    Organization = VBA.Trim(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, 7))
    JobTitle = VBA.Trim(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, 8))

    Print #FileNum, "BEGIN:VCARD"
    Print #FileNum, "VERSION:3.0"

    Print #FileNum, "N:" & FirstName & ";" & LastName & ";;;"
    Print #FileNum, "FN:" & FullName
    Print #FileNum, "ORG:" & Organization
    Print #FileNum, "TITLE:" & JobTitle
    Print #FileNum, "TEL;TYPE=HOME,VOICE:" & PhoneHome
    Print #FileNum, "TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:" & PhoneWork
    Print #FileNum, "EMAIL:" & EmailAddress

    Print #FileNum, "END:VCARD"
    iRow = iRow + 1
Wend

'Close The File
Close #FileNum
MsgBox "Contacts Converted to Saved To: " & OutFilePath & " 
End Sub
```

thankyou, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution similar to these which works using the output from Outlook web as a CSV file and creating a vCard text file which is correctly formatted for loading to
Apple iCloud contacts. I used it recently to transfer a friends contacts from Microsoft Outlook web to Apple iPhone contacts.

```
Option Explicit
Sub sbMakeVCard()
    ' https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2426.txt
    Dim iLastRow As Integer
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim sVCard As String
    Dim sN As String
    Dim sFN As String
    Dim sTel As String
    Dim sEmail As String
    Dim sNote As String
    ' Check that the sheet has come from Outlook web - Column 61 should be "Notes"
    If Trim(Cells(1, 61)) <> "Notes" Then
        MsgBox "Invalid format Outlook worksheet " & Trim(Cells(1, 61))
    End If
    ' Must be something in first column for a valid entry
    iLastRow = fnGetLastRow(1, 1)
    sVCard = ""
    For iRow = 2 To iLastRow
        sVCard = sVCard & "BEGIN:VCARD" & vbCr & vbLf & "VERSION:3.0" & vbCr & vbLf & "PRODID:-//user10186832//iOS 15.6//EN" & vbCr & vbLf
        sN = "N:" & Trim(Cells(iRow, 3)) & ";" & Trim(Cells(iRow, 1)) & ";;;" & vbCr & vbLf
        sFN = "FN: " & Trim(Cells(iRow, 1)) & " " & Trim(Cells(iRow, 3)) & " " & vbCr & vbLf
        If Mid(Trim(Cells(iRow, 12)), 1, 2) = "07" Then
            ' Put the +44 in for WhatsApp
            ' Outlook heading "Home Phone" (column 12) is where all the phone numbers are
            sTel = "TEL;type=HOME;type=VOICE:+44 " & Mid(Trim(Cells(iRow, 12)), 3, Len(Trim(Cells(iRow, 12)))) & " " & vbCr & vbLf
        Else
            sTel = "TEL;type=HOME;type=VOICE: " & Trim(Cells(iRow, 12)) & " " & vbCr & vbLf
        End If
        If Mid(Trim(Cells(iRow, 12)), 1, 1) = "" Then
            sTel = ""
        End If
        'EMAIL;TYPE=internet,pref:jane_doe@abc.com
        'Outlook heading "E-mail Address" (column 9)
        If Mid(Trim(Cells(iRow, 9)), 1, 1) = "" Then
            sEmail = ""
        Else
            sEmail = "EMAIL;TYPE=internet,pref:" & Trim(Cells(iRow, 9)) & " " & vbCr & vbLf
        End If
        'NOTE:This fax number is operational 0800 to 1715 EST\, Mon-Fri.
        If Mid(Trim(Cells(iRow, 61)), 1, 1) = "" Then
            sNote = ""
        Else
            sNote = "NOTE:" & Trim(Cells(iRow, 61)) & " " & vbCr & vbLf
        End If
        sVCard = sVCard & sN & sFN & sTel & sEmail & sNote
        sVCard = sVCard & "REV:" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SSZ") & vbCr & vbLf & "END:VCARD" & vbCr & vbLf
    Next iRow
    Call fnOutputToFile(sVCard)
    MsgBox "Done..."
End Sub
```